# Codeigniter help - active record and looping in controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, foreach

I am working with a codeigniter application at the moment, and it lets you filter jobs, based on various critieria, however it is not quite working right, basically, what should happen is that after filtering a user should be shown a result in this format,

```
<section style="display: block;" class="employer">
    <div class="job_holder">
    <img src="http://lcl.doctrine.com/media/uploads/users/large_moovjob_large4.gif" alt="Test Company" height="148" width="198">
        <dl>
    <dt>2</dt>
    <dd>Matches</dd>
    </dl>
    <!--<a href="" class="fave">Fave</a>-->
    <ul class="job_listings">
            <li> 
                + <a href="http://lcl.doctrine.com/jobwall/getjob/4" class="openjob">
            PHP Backend Web Developer
                  </a>
    </li>
    <li>
            + <a href="http://lcl.doctrine.com/jobwall/getjob/5" class="openjob">
                Website Designer                            
              </a>
             </li>
             </ul>
     </div>
    </section>
```

However what I get is that markup repeated twice, I looping over an array that looks like this,

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [job_id] => 4
            [job_title] => PHP Backend Web Developer
            [salary] => 23000
            [job_tags] => IT,Media
            [retrain] => no
            [job_extras] => We offer a very generous bonus scheme, including a company car, profit bonuses and a pension package.

            [job_summary] => The job consists of a 60/40 spilt of PHP and front end skills, you will be expected to be proficient in, PHP, OO, MySQL and JAVASCRIPT
            [job_description] => The job is a 60/40 split between the front and the backend of coding. You will be working within a team of 4 using an inhouse framework and where applicable an in house CMS.

For working hours of 9-5.30 (we try not to stay too late but sometimes this is unnavoidable) you will be paid ?23,000, you will also be given a company car, and 1% of all yearly profits, we will also match any pension contributions that you make.



            [company_name] => Test Company
            [company_summary] => Test company is excatly what it says it is a test company, we have created this test company so that we can see that moovjob is functioning as it should be and that everything is upload, saving, applying and generally saving as we would expect. Hello
            [logo_small] => small_moovjob_small12.png
            [logo_large] => large_moovjob_large4.gif
            [employer_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [job_id] => 5
            [job_title] => Website Designer
            [salary] => 28000
            [job_tags] => Media,Marketing
            [retrain] => no
            [job_extras] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam enim nisl, sodales dignissim tempus in, placerat id enim. Aenean eget diam velit. Morbi quis erat mi. Donec metus sem, consectetur at malesuada ac, iaculis nec arcu. Morbi libero leo, rhoncus ac vestibulum quis, vehicula nec metus. Vestibulum quis luctus erat. In varius accumsan ornare. Ut ullamcorper bibendum lorem ut elementum.
            [job_summary] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam enim nisl, sodales dignissim tempus in, placerat id enim. Aenean eget diam velit. Morbi quis erat mi. Donec metus sem, consectetur at malesuada ac, iaculis nec arcu. Morbi libero leo, rhoncus ac vestibulum quis, vehicula nec metus. Vestibulum quis luctus erat.us erat. In varius accumsan ornare. Ut ullamcorper bibendum lorem ut elementum.
            [job_description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam enim nisl, sodales dignissim tempus in, placerat id enim. Aenean eget diam velit. Morbi quis erat mi. Donec metus sem, consectetur at malesuada ac, iaculis nec arcu. Morbi libero leo, rhoncus ac vestibulum quis, vehicula nec metus. Vestibulum quis luctus erat. In varius accumsan ornare. Ut ullamcorper bibendum lorem ut elementum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam enim nisl, sodales dignissim tempus in, placerat id enim. Aenean eget diam velit. Morbi quis erat mi. Donec metus sem, consectetur at malesuada ac, iaculis nec arcu. Morbi libero leo, rhoncus ac vestibulum quis, vehicula nec metus. Vestibulum quis luctus erat. In varius accumsan ornare. Ut ullamcorper bibendum lorem ut elementum.
            [company_name] => Test Company
            [company_summary] => Test company is excatly what it says it is a test company, we have created this test company so that we can see that moovjob is functioning as it should be and that everything is upload, saving, applying and generally saving as we would expect. Hello
            [logo_small] => small_moovjob_small12.png
            [logo_large] => large_moovjob_large4.gif
            [employer_id] => 1
        )

)
```

I loop over it by doing the following code,

```
<?php if(is_array($jobs)) : ?>
<pre><?php print_r($jobs); ?></pre>
<?php $count = count($jobs); ?>
<?php foreach ($jobs as $j) : ?>
    <section class="employer">
        <div class="job_holder">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/uploads/users/<?php echo $j['logo_large']; ?>" width="198" height="148" alt="<?php echo $j['company_name']; ?>"/>
            <dl>
                <dt><?php echo $count; ?></dt>
                <dd>Matches</dd>
            </dl>
            <!--<a href="" class="fave">Fave</a>-->
             <ul class="job_listings">
                    <?php foreach ($jobs as $j) : ?>
                        <?php $job = $j['job_title']; ?>
                        <li>
                            + <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jobwall/getjob/<?php echo $j['job_id']; ?>" class="openjob">
                                <?php echo $job; ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Basically what I need to do, is echo out the company name and then the companies jobs, and then move on, what it is doing at the moment, is echoing out the comapny name and then its jobs and then repeating itself as `$jobs` has 2 results in it, but they are both for the same company.

The code in my model is below,

```
public function search($salary = null, $location = null, $tags = null, $quick_tags = null)
{
    $this->db->select('job_id, job_title, salary, job_tags, retrain, job_extras, job_summary, job_description,  company_name, company_summary, logo_small, logo_large, employers.employer_id');
    $this->db->from('jobs');
    $this->db->join('employers', 'employers.employer_id = jobs.employer_id', 'left');
    if(isset($salary)) {
        $this->db->where('jobs.salary >=', $salary);
    }
    if(isset($location)) {
        $this->db->where('jobs.city', $location);
    }
    if(isset($tags)) {
        $this->db->like('jobs.job_tags', $tags);
    }
    if(isset($quick_tags) && is_array($quick_tags)) {
        foreach ($quick_tags as $index => $value) {
            if ($index == 0)
                $this->db->like('jobs.job_tags', $value);
            else
                $this->db->or_like('jobs.job_tags', $value);
        }
    }
    $this->db->group_by('jobs.job_title');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve a consistent result like

```
Employer
    job posting 1
    job posting 2
Other employer
    job posting 1
```

You might have to alter you query to sort your jobs by employer first to be sure that the jobs are grouped together.

Then by looping through your data (untested pseudo-code)

```
employerCache = '';
for ($jobs as $job) {
   if ($job['company_name'] != employerCache) {
       // display company/employer header
       $employerCache = $job['company_name'];
   }
   // display job posting
}
```

That will give you 1 loop instead of two nested loops on the same dataset